# Admin Directory services in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get all users information from my domain, but when i run this function in apps script it gives an error - not authorized to access this API/resource . I have enabled the api service from console also .

```
    function listAllUsers() {
     var pageToken, page;
  do {

  page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
  domain: 'mydomain.com',
  orderBy: 'givenName',
  maxResults: 100,
  pageToken: pageToken
  });
 var users = page.users;
 if (users) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
  }
  } else {
  Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
 pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
 } while (pageToken);
 }
```

Comment: Have you done what it says in the documentation?: "Note: This is an advanced service that must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced?hl=es). Additionally, the Admin SDK must be enabled on your domain, as described in the API's [prerequisites documentaion](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites?hl=es).". See [Admin SDK Directory Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory)

Comment: Yes i have enabled the services before executing it . It was still giving error thats why i posted on stack overflow.Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out... at least, for myself.

it was the domain field.
Line 5 : domain: 'mydomain.com',

That needed to be updated to the domain I was working with.